# Colocar contraseña a MySQL Server en cuenta root en Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, linux, contraseña

Instalé Kubuntu 18.04 y como siempre procedo a instalar apache, mysql, phpmyadmin y php. El caso es que esta vez al momento de instalar **sudo apt install mysql-server** no se me pidió que colocara una contraseña, sino que la instalación termino si errores. Ahora al intentar acceder a **http://localhost/phpmyadmin** como **root** no puedo. Lo intenté sin contraseña como era lógico y me da el siguiente error: **El inicio de sesión sin contraseña está prohibido por la configuración (ver AllowNoPassword)**

Luego recordé el comando **sudo mysql_secure_installation** logré supuestamente colocar una contraseña a root pero al intentar acceder vía phpmyadmin me da el error: **#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'**. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que asignarle una contraseña por el uso de `mysql_secure_installation`

Primero deten el servicio de mysql:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

Inicia mysql de una forma alternativa para no pedir contraseña:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Algunas veces marca un error:

```
$ mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

Para solventar esto solo se necesita crear el directorio y asignarle permisos:

```
$ mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
$ chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Si no te marca error o ya creaste el archivo faltante prosigues con para entrar a la consola de mysql:

```
mysql -u root
```

Ahora usamos la base de mysql:

```
mysql> use mysql
```

Le asignamos una contraseña al usuario root cambiando el valor tuContraseña por la contraseña que quieres tener :

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('tuContraseña');
```

Recargamos los privilegios:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Salimos de mysql:

```
mysql> quit;
```

Detenemos el servicio de mysql y lo arrancamos de forma normal:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Ahora entramos a mysql con la nueva contraseña que definiste:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Ok. todo bien hasta: mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('tuContraseña'); Ahí me muestra el siguiente error: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement. Creo que es al camino pero algo no cuadra

Answer (score 0):

Hola compañero intenta ingresar al archivo config.inic.php y verifica que la contraseña que ingresaste al principio coincida dentro del archivo o bien colocala en el mismo, te dejo un link donde se explica este proceso
https://eldesvandejose.com/2016/09/25/cambiar-la-contrasena-de-root-en-phpmyadmin/

Para ir al archivo de configuración de PHPMyAdmin. Su nombre es config.inc.php. 
Para abrirlo basta con escribir en la terminal:
**$ sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

NOTA:Si estás usando otra herramienta, o has instalado los servidores manualmente, deberás buscarlo en la ruta correspondiente.El número de línea puede variar, dependiendo de tu instalación MySQL (en tu caso, puede no ser la línea 21).

Dentro del archivo Ve a la línea 21, donde encontraras lo siguiente:

**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';**
**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';**

Cambia el valor de la contraseña por la que habías creado:

**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';**

Graba los cambios,( tecla **CTRL + X** y oprime **S/Y**) y listo ya lo tienes. A partir de este momento, el usuario root ya tiene la clave indicada.

Basta con ingresar de nuevo a phpmyadmin y entrar con las credenciales indicadas arriba.

Comment: por favor añade lo relevante de la información de ese enlacem pues las respuestas que son solo links se consideran de baja calidad; por otro lado si esa web deja de servir la información quedará innacesible